# How to pass a file name as parameter, create and then read the file

Tags: java, file, file-io

I have a method as follows:

```
    public(String input_filename, String output_filename)
   {
//some content
    }
```

how to create an  input_filename at run time and read the input_filename .I have to pass input_filename as a parameter

Please be patient as I am new to Java

Comment: Can you please make it compile first? Then call the function with two parameters.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [help]. You are supposed to do research before posting on this site, failing to do so will result in down- and possibly even close-votes. That involves you searching for "*java how to read file*" and *"java how to write file"*. Also, you need to show your attempt to the problem and explain with which step you are having difficulty.

Comment: That being said, use `Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filename))` and `Files.write(Paths.get(filename))` and other methods of the `Files` class, such as `Files.createFile` etc.

Comment: In case all you want to do is to copy the file, use `Files.copy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a complete sample:

Save it as Sample.java

compile it with: `javac Sample.java`

run it with: `java Sample "in.txt" "out.txt"`

or: `java Sample`

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        if(args.length == 2)
        {
            doFileStuff(args[0],args[1]);
        }
        else {
            doFileStuff("in.txt","out.txt");
        }
    }

    public static void doFileStuff(String input_filename, String output_filename) throws IOException {

        if(!Files.exists(Paths.get(input_filename)))
        {
            System.err.println("file not exist: " + input_filename);
            return;
        }

        if(!Files.exists(Paths.get(output_filename)))
        {
            System.err.println("file still exist, do not overwrite it: " + output_filename);
            return;
        }

        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(input_filename)));

        content += "\nHas added something";

        Files.write(Paths.get(output_filename), content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }
}
```

Comment: For big files use Streams as here the file is loaded to the RAM

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what you want to do with this method, but I hope this can help you a bit.
If you want inputs during runtime, use the `Scanner` class.  [A guide on how to use it here](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_user_input.asp)

Also if you want an output in your class you should use "return", and not have it as a parameter.

Do note that you haven't named your class yet, or specified the output type.

How it could look:

```
public String className(String input){
    return input;
}
```